# Nested lappy in r

Tags: r

So I have function that takes 2 argument to read txt files from a site. The arguments are 1 the names of city and the 2nd one is the type of data. I have 2 list to pass it down as arguments which are the list of cities and the list of type of data. How could i use nested lapply to read the files from the site?
My attempt of the code look something like this:

```
cities <- c("sydney","brisbane"...)
typedatas <- c("Max", "Avg","Min")

url<- "https:/sitename/datasets/"

read.text <- function(city, typedata){
    c(url,typedata,"/year/",city, ".txt) >%>
    paste0()
    }
finaldata <- lapply(cities, function(x) lapply(typedatas,function(x){read.ts})) %>% set_names(cities)
```

it creates a big list but the did not completely read the files. The output would be like below:

final data list [10]

- sydney list[3]
- function
- function
- function
- brisbane list[3]
- function...
  ....

how can i make it read and also appropriately name the dataframes using the type of data for each cities.

Comment: i would just make a vector of file paths `sprintf('%s/%s/year/%s.txt', url, typedatas, rep(cities, each = length(typedatas)))` then if you _really_ need a list of lists, you can use `split` on a list to created a nested list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of hard to do this without a reproducible example but you can try this:

```
cities <- c("sydney","brisbane")
typedatas <- c("Max", "Avg","Min")

url<- "https:/sitename/datasets/"

read.text <- function(city, typedata){
  paste0(url,typedata,"/year/",city, ".txt")
}
finaldata <- lapply(cities, function(cty){
  lapply(typedatas,function(ds_type){
    read.text(cty, ds_type)
  })
}) %>% set_names(cities)
```

Notice that your `read.text` function doesn't actually read the file but only creates the hyperlink to it so you will need to add some kind of function to actually read the file.